# Problem with executing a method concurrently in a class with different parameters passed through loop using ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, executorservice

I am trying to write a program to process an operation on large number of employees about approx one million. I am using ExecutorService to parallelize the operation to create threads in a loop of employees with pool size of 1000.
( I have 24 core(48 logical core) intel cpu with 128gb ram server). My operation includes many database accesses, that's why I am using thread pool size of 1000.

My goal is to process the operation on employees while main thread should wait for all other threads to complete the jobs and then returns with process result.
Problem is that main thread returns after creating threads immediately.

Servlet code:

```
public class EmployeeProcess extends HttpServlet {

protected void doGet(....) {
  employeeDAO.executePrepareReport();
}

}
```

second class:

```
public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO {

   public void executePrepareReport() {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1000);
        // method reference introduced in Java 8
        for(Employee employee : comp.listOfEmp) {

            executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    prepareEmpReport(employee);
                }
            });
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        //executorService.awaitTermination();
    }

   @Override
   public void prepareEmpReport(Employee  employee) {

   // process employee report with database accesses

   }

}
```

Please suggest correction in the code or alternative efficient way to do it

Comment: Why did you comment out awaitTermination()?

Comment: I dont know how to use it, what parameters to pass

Comment: Also, you assume unlimited parallelism in the database. Depending on the nature of the request, having hundreds of DB requests executing in parallel may be counterproductive.

Comment: Then please ask the appropriate question: "How do I use `awaitTermination()`?". In any case you pass in the timeout - a period long enough for you to expect that all thread finished their work, or a period that makes the result of that work irrelevant.

Comment: that is what i was unable to estimate the expected time of threads to finish the work.

Comment: you should not take an approach which is based on an assumed time taken by thread to complete work. There are better ways like Countdown latch or old join()

Comment: Don't create a new executor and potentially a thousand threads *for each new request*. The executor should belong to the service class (and probably have a much lower parallelism, like half the connection limit in your connection pool) and be used by all incoming service requests.

Answer (score 2):

There are different approach to solve this problem.

Two common approaches are:

- CountDownLatch
- ExecutorService.invokeAll

---

You can use a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html):

> A synchronization aid that allows one or more threads to wait until a set of operations being performed in other threads completes.

---

You can use the method [`invokeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)) of `ExecutorService`:

> Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their status and results when all complete. Future.isDone() is true for each element of the returned list. Note that a completed task could have terminated either normally or by throwing an exception. The results of this method are undefined if the given collection is modified while this operation is in progress.